# applying transform on an overlapped element

Tags: html, css

hey guys I was working on transforms and testing them on overlapping divs and I couldn't make the div that is beneath to transform too

is it possible to do it without any JS?

as you can see the purple div on hover transforms and disappears and I want the red div under it to slightly rotate too and I couldn't make It work

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 2%;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 13px;
}
.box1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}
.box2:hover {
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to `rotate` box1 and box2 if either one is hovered? You should be more specific as to what you need to accomplish.

Comment: yes sorry I need them both rotated when I hover on box2 I want box 1 to transform aswell

Comment: May I ask if there is suppose to be anhything more than just that covered,colored square? ... or should it contain other elements?

Comment: @LGSon no only these squares its originally supposed to be an image and a cover that hides the images I just wanted to make a simulation before I start the work the point was just to make the purple box disappear and make the red one rotate a bit that's all :P nothing more nothing less

Comment: Ok, then you can do this using pseudo elements, no need for all that extra markup ... I'll update my answer with a suggestion

Comment: Updated with something more appropiate, I hope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on a comment, now using pseudo elements instead of a doubled markup

```css
.container {
  padding: 2%;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  background-color: purple;
}
.box::before {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1);
  background-size: cover;
}
.box:hover::before,
.box:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.box:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's an interesting way :O that means if I want other images all I need is a few more classes but the code itself doesn't change much just the url

Comment: @Decapitar Yes, you can swap images using classes

Answer (score 1):

This is what you could do

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.box:hover .top,
.box:hover .cover {
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.top {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="cover"></div>
      <div class="top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="cover"></div>
      <div class="top"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this method but is it possible to do how I had it? 2 sections 1 regular and 1 cover?

Comment: @Decapitar As far as I know it's not possible with CSS3, it would be possible if you were able to select a parent based on the child, but there is no such selector in CSS3.

Comment: @Decapitar No, it is not possible (today) without script ... either with the given markup change, or all 4 boxes in same parent, and it is possible with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Just brainstorming: How about creating a parent by putting both divs inside a div3, make div3 transparent, position with z-index above the other ones, capturing the hover. Select the other divs then simply as childs of div3:hover.